# Does CLion support custom input? If yes, where do I enter them?

Tags: c++, input, clion

How can I give input to `std::cin` after running a program in CLion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your program from within CLion, you should see a tab opened in the `Run` window at the bottom of the screen (default location), with the name of your program as the tab title.  Click the cursor inside the window and you will be able to enter your text.